# Enzyme/Jest static method mock not running

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test out an imported static method, that ought be run on button click. Here is the component, on which the test ought be run:

```
const NextButton = (props: ISubmitButtonProps) => (
    <button
        onClick={Service.goToNext}
        className="col-2 submit"
        type="submit"
        disabled={props.submitting}>
        Next
    </button>
);

export default NextButton;
```

Now, I want to test whether the method `goToNext` is actually being run.
For that I've used an example from [here](https://medium.com/@masonlgoetz/mock-static-class-methods-in-jest-1ceda967b47f) and have added a mock looking fine, like this:

```
const goToNextMock = jest.fn();
jest.mock('Services/service', () => ({
        default: class {
            public static goToNext() {
                goToNextMock(); //the jest.fn from above
            }
        }
    })
);
```

And later wrote the test for it, simply simulating the click event, and then checking if the `jest.fn()` was run:

```
it('should call goToNext on button click', () => {
        //button is set before as shallow(<NextButton submitting={false}/>);
        button.simulate('click');
        expect(goToNext).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

The problem is, reasons unknown, the test does not persist. Giving me a

> Expected mock function to have been called.

EDIT: Same result would occur when attempting to mock it this way (mind the additional `preventDefault()`

```
it('should call goToNextReport on button click', () => {
    const mock = jest.fn();
    Service.goToNext = mock.bind(Service);

    button.simulate('click', { preventDefault() {} });

    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

I'm fairly new to JEST and js testing. It seems the mock was done properly, yet still I can't get the method to be checked.

Any ideas on the subject?
All help would be amazing!
EDIT: The issue was also submitted to the JEST github channel: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jest.mock('Services/service', () => ({
    goToNext: jest.fn()
}));
```